# Как выбрать c объекта несколько значений?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть объект, у которого свойство - это число например:

```
{
 1: 123,
 2: 2323,
 3: 444,
 4: 112321,
 5: 324234,
 6: 2342,
 7: 23423
}
```

В функцию должно приходить число, и относительно него выбираться несколько свойств с объекта, например:

```
function func(num){
 return 
}
func(3) //должно вернуть массив свойств числа и 2х следующих, тоисть 3,4,5
```

Помогите пожалуйста, что-то никак не может дойти как сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
 1: 123,
 2: 2323,
 3: 444,
 4: 112321,
 5: 324234,
 6: 2342,
 7: 23423
}

function func(num){
  var i;
  for (key in obj) {
    if(key == num){
      i = 0;
    }
    if(i < 3){
      console.log(key + ':' + obj[key]);
    }
    i++;
  }
}

func(3);
```